# HotChocolate: Dynamic schemas and how to update filters accordingly

Tags: asp.net-core, graphql, hotchocolate

**NOTE: If you do know that the below is not possible, this information is just as valuable.**

Im checking out [HotChocolate](https://chillicream.com/docs/hotchocolate/) and Ive looked into the [dynamic schemas](https://chillicream.com/blog/2021/09/27/hot-chocolate-12#dynamic-schemas)

I have taken the code in your [Github-example](https://github.com/ChilliCream/hotchocolate-examples/tree/master/misc/TypeModules/DynamicTypes) This works ok. I have extended our Product-type like so:

//Same json as in your Github-sample, new properties are "color" and some more

```
foreach (var field in type.GetProperty("fields").EnumerateArray())
{
    string name = field.GetString();
    typeDefinition.Fields.Add(new ObjectFieldDefinition(field.GetString()!, type: TypeReference.Parse("String"), pureResolver: ctx =>
    {
        var product = ctx.Parent<Product>();
        return product.SubTypeSpecific.ContainsKey(name) ? product.SubTypeSpecific[name] : null;
    }));
}
```

now I have "moved out" dynamic properties from a Dictionary (That is a sub-object in my documentDb) to own properties. Works well.

BUT:

1. How can I extend my ProductFilter in the same fashion?

I would like to extend my current Product-filter so its possible to search on the new dynamic property "color"

```
getProducts(where : color : {eq :"blue" }}) {...}
```

I can create new FilterInputDefinition, but not extend existing filter (because there is no FilterInputTypeExtensions.CreateUnsafe()

2. If I manage to create the new filter, is there any way to update the IQueryable-generation so that the inputed color ("blue")
   So the query to my CosmosDb will be created automatically?

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you find any solution?

Comment: still no... Ive tried the support,github, reaching out to the developers, nothing

Comment: No solution yet?

Comment: No ...13 more chars

Comment: @Cowborg can you paste the link to the Github issue here please so can take a look, keen to see a solution for this as well

Comment: @Cowborg No solution yet?

Comment: We have dropped hot chocolate for now. So I cant say that it solved or not solved